# An Error: 'Numpy.str_' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, attributes

I tried to run a test on Crab(an open source recommender system) based on python3. Then an error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Dennis/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scikits/crab/datasets/base.py", line 201, in load_sample_movies
    data_songs[u_ix][i_ix] = float(rating)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "b'3.0'"
```

I tried to use 'decode()' to convert the string, but it's not working:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Dennis/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scikits/crab/datasets/base.py", line 202, in load_sample_movies
    rating = rating.decode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'numpy.str_' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: "b'3.0'" is unicode, the Py3 default string type.  So it has an `encode`, but not `decode`.   But that doesn't get ride of the extra layer of quoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `rating` is a string within a string, so when you try casting a string like `"b'3.0'"` into a float, it gives a `valueError` because you still have the `b` in front which cannot be converted into float.

I imagine you need the byte encoding in front of the `'3.0'`, so one way would be to evaluate `rating` to convert it from a string to bytes before typecasting it into a float (beware though, [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) can have some safety issues).

```
>>> type(eval(rating))
<class 'bytes'>
>>> data_songs[u_ix][i_ix] = float(eval(rating))
```